# Why keyword search using AND operator does not fetch search result in php

Tags: php, mysql

I one table including id,title and text. From a drop down menu I let user to select title and text. Based on title and text I want to show search result.But when i write the query using `AND` operator it does not show any result, although the matching data is available in the database. Can anybody help me to figure this out?

This is  Query searching code

```
$search_value=$_POST["search"];
$services=$_POST["services"];

$sql="select * from articles where title like '%$search_value%' AND text like '%services%' ";


$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
// output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "id: " . $row["id"]. " - Name: " . $row["title"]. $row["text"];
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
```

This is drop down list

```
<form action="search.php" method="post">

    <select class="form-control" name="search" id="select1">                   
    <option value="Ampara">Ampara</option>
    <option value="Anuradhapura">Anuradhapura</option>
    <option value="Badulla">Badulla</option>
    <option value="Batticaloa">Batticaloa</option>
    <option value="Colombo">Colombo</option>
    </select>
    <select class="form-control" name="services" >                   
    <option value="Architecture">Architecture</option>
    <option value="Astrology">Astrology</option>
    <option value="Electrical">Electrical</option>
    <option value="Landscaping">Landscaping</option>
    <option value="Hardware">Hardware</option>
    <option value="Plumbing">Plumbing</option>
</select>
```

**This is screenshot of my database table**
[image]

Comment: Can you give an example of your data and one example of your expected result? Hard to help you with this theoretical information.

Comment: @dns_nx I added my database screenshot. I check whether $services is passed to search.php. It is passing as well

Comment: Check the solution of @Praveen. That is the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please replace your query with following, 
You have missed $ sign in services variable for text field in the query

```
$sql="select * from articles where title like '%" . $search_value . "%' AND text like '%" . $services . "%' ";
```

Comment: you should prepare your statement or be careful to escape the user input data, else you open door for sqlinjections